# WooCommerce Payment Gateway not showing on checkout page

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I have enabled the PayPal standard gateway. This is currently the showing payment method on the checkout page. I have installed an SSL and have an HTTPS:// how ever when i try to enable the PayPal Pro Payment Gateway (in sandbox mode) the Checkout page only displays the Paypal standard method and does not give the familiar radio buttons to select the method. Only method available is the paypal standard.

I also tried enabling the Cheque payment gateway but that also does not display on checkout page

Is there any way to fix this so the credit card input Paypal pro payment method displays on the checkout page?

The site is https://www.dowelmax.com

Answer (score 7):

I had this very same problem and found this page in researching the answer. You mentioned that it turned out to be a conflict with a currency switcher plugin. I had one of those installed, so tried disabling that and indeed my problem resolved too!

To further clarify a solution for anyone else in the same boat - it may be that you need to enable specific payment gateways for each available currency. Above and beyond the general WooCommerce enable option. (Even for your base currency)

This enabled me to fix the problem AND keep my currency switcher plugin active.
In my case, it was Aelia Currency Switcher. They have a support note on it here:
https://aelia.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/158712-one-or-more-payment-methods-don-t-appear-after-installing-the-currency-switcher-how-can-i-fix-it-

Comment: Well that was a fun two hours trying to figure this one out...Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what plugin you are using in WooCommerce, you need to enable force secure checkout. Once [force secure checkout](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/) is enabled typically PayPal Payments Pro will show up on the checkout page.

1. Click on WooCommerce
2. Settings
3. Checkout
4. Checkout Options

Place a check mark next to force secure checkout (not force http) and then save. Also make certain that PayPal Payments Pro is enabled on the list of gateways.
This image is from the WooCommerce Documentation on Woothemes. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had Force secure checkout enabled. Still no paypal pro payment method. I'm not even getting a payment method for cheques or BACS when i enable them

Comment: Looks like it was a Currency Switcher plugin that was causing the problem. I deactivated it, and now it works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this problem with this instructions : 
**Admin** > **Woocommerce Settings** > **Payment** > **Manage** (Your checkout) Active your API permission or information and you get solve.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I was also face this type of problem but I was resolve with these instruction.

1. Enable define (`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in wp-config.php);
2. Goto checkout page and refresh page.
3. Now showing some warning and fatal error.
4. Solve fatal error and refresh again checkout page and now it's showing payment option and order place button.

I hope this instruction will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a mistake with **Live Email address**

The + in my email was replaced by a space :

`mymail+foo@mail.com` > `mymail foo@mail.com`